# Print value of a input-field in HTML

Tags: jquery, input

when I click the button, the value of these both input fields should display in the cells.

```
<input id="input_for_left_column" placeholder="Minuten" type="number">
<input id="input_for_left_column" placeholder="Minuten" type="number">
<button type="submit" id="submit_for_table">Add</button>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td id="left_column"></td>
    <td id="right_column"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$(function(){
  function add_value() {
    $("#left_column").val($('#input_for_left_column').text(val());
    $("#right_column").val($('#input_for_right_column').text(val());
  }
  $('#submit_for_table').click(add_value);
 });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the text of a table cell you'd use `.text()` and to get the value of an input you'd use `.val()`
Also you have `input_for_left_column` as the id for the two inputs.

```js
$(function(){
  function add_value() {
    $("#left_column").text($('#input_for_left_column').val());
    $("#right_column").text($('#input_for_right_column').val());
  }
  $('#submit_for_table').click(add_value);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_for_left_column" placeholder="Minuten" type="number">
<input id="input_for_right_column" placeholder="Minuten" type="number">
<button type="submit" id="submit_for_table">Add</button>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td id="left_column"></td>
    <td id="right_column"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```